# Method throws exception that java says isn't handled

Tags: java, passwords, salt, throws

When I try to run this code in my Main class my IDE pops up and says that I'm not handling the exception I'm throwing at the beginning of my method.

```
public byte[] generateSalt() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{

        // VERY important to use SecureRandom instead of just Random
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

        // Generate a 8 byte (64 bit) salt as recommended by RSA PKCS5
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        random.nextBytes(salt);

        return salt;

}
```

Comment: So what is your question? If you don't know what to do with the exception I suggest you rethrow it just like you do in this method.

Comment: where are you calling `generateSalt`? Are you handling the exception there? Where does the compiler complain?

Comment: where are you calling this method, post  that part

Comment: Why is it important to use s specific SecureRandom implementation. You can just use the default `SecureRandom` and it won't throw an Exception for you to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this method is throwing en exception, than every method that uses it needs to either catch that exception, or throw it as well.

If a method that uses `generateSalt` is not doing one of the two, then the compiler will complain about unhandled exception.

The solution is simple, on the calling method either add `throws NoSuchAlgorithmException` to the signature, or do this:

```
try {
  generateSalt();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  // do something with the exception
}
```